# How to Replace Text in a cell Using Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say that in my Column A, I have a dropdown menu for "YES" and "NO".

```
If A1 == "YES"
   B1 = "CONGRATS!"
If A2 == "NO"
   B2 = "SORRY!"
```

I have applied the code below in column B's conditional formatting but didn't worked. Any possible option?

```
=IF(A1<>"YES", "SORRY","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=IF(A1="YES","CONGRATS!",IF(A1="NO","SORRY!",""))
```

Comment: You need to use the formula in the formula bar, not conditional formatting.

Comment: can we prevent the user not to update the cell value once the condition has been met?

Comment: @PeterS You would put the formula in make sure that the cell is locked then protect the sheet, then the user will not be able to change the cell at all and only by changing the value in A will it change the value in B.

Comment: @ScottCraner is it possible to lock only the cell based on the value of the another cell? For example if cell A1 was selected as "No" B1 will display NA and user will not able to edit this cell. If A2 was selected as "Yes", user will be able to add value to B2

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are trying to create a formula that will change column B's value when A is equal to Yes or No?

I don't think this is an issue relating to conditional formatting, rather a simple formula should do the trick.

```
=IF(A1="YES","CONGRATS!",IF(A1="NO","SORRY!"))
```

Comment: The only problem here is that, I want to prevent the user to update the cell value as a result of the contion

Comment: I would recommend the formula approach while using a locked sheet. This would prevent the user from changing the formula. I've been checking for a few minutes now and to the best of my knowledge conditional formatting does not support adding text to a cell, since strings are not "formats."